# echo container image:tag (URI) in kubernetes readinessProbe or livenessProbe

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

I have many versions and tags of containers used by Deployment in k8s (and hence many log groups).
It would be nice if i could display the container URI and tag in a `readinessProbe` or `livenessProbe` which then flows to persisted logging.

Basically so that I know my Pod whose logs I am viewing is running on the correct image.

I thought of simply `echo`ing it as a container variable, so i thought of setting the container image URI as a container variable in the Pod manifest.

The docs at [k8s EnvVarSource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#envvarsource-v1-core) says it only supports certain fields for `fieldRef`, importantly, it doesn't support grabbing the `spec.containers` `image` field.

Anyone has any smart ideas how I might achieve this in other ways?
Or when/if does the kubernetes team support this?

**UPDATE:**
i found that doing `echo` under `readinessProbe.exec.command` works (the Pod is Ready status) but the `echo` output does not flow to the logs.
Only the application (server) output appear in the logs in my logging backend (CloudWatch).

Comment: i just realized i can see it in Kubernetes Dashboard and probably through some `kubectl` commands. But it'd still be nice to see it in the logs.

Comment: As the [Alex Robinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1925481/alex-robinson)  explained in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34455040/kubernetes-liveness-probe-logging): The output of successful probes is recorded if Kubelet has a [log level of at least --v=4, in which case it'll be in the Kubelet's logs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/5828836e7c4abb4666a845adb607f1b2a65a1a76/pkg/probe/exec/exec.go#L38). There should be an option of redirecting that output into the CloudWatch and other monitoring tools. I will try to test it and will comeback with confirmation.

Comment: sorry @cryanbhu I was not able to recreate that due to technical restrictions I have. Did you manage to succeed to go further with this case?

Comment: nope, i still did not manage to find a solution