# Should a Kubernetes readiness probe emit an event when the container transitions to ready?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm starting to introduce [liveness and readiness probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/) in my services, and I'm not sure if I've succeeded in getting it working or not, because I can't confidently interpret the status reported by `kubectl`.

`kubectl describe pod mypod` gives me something like this:

```
Name:           myapp-5798dd798c-t7dqs
Namespace:      dev
Node:           docker-for-desktop/192.168.65.3
Start Time:     Wed, 24 Oct 2018 13:22:54 +0200
Labels:         app=myapp
                pod-template-hash=1354883547
Annotations:    version: v2
Status:         Running
IP:             10.1.0.103
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/myapp-5798dd798c
Containers:
  myapp:
    Container ID:   docker://5d39cb47d2278eccd6d28c1eb35f93112e3ad103485c1c825de634a490d5b736
    Image:          myapp:latest
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:61dafd0c208e2519d0165bf663e4b387ce4c2effd9237fb29fb48d316eda07ff
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 24 Oct 2018 13:23:06 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Liveness:       http-get http://:80/healthz/live delay=0s timeout=10s period=60s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:80/healthz/ready delay=3s timeout=3s period=5s #success=1 #failure=3
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-gvnc2 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          True
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  default-token-gvnc2:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-gvnc2
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age   From                         Message
  ----     ------                 ----  ----                         -------
  Normal   Scheduled              84s   default-scheduler            Successfully assigned myapp-5798dd798c-t7dqs to docker-for-desktop
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  84s   kubelet, docker-for-desktop  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-gvnc2"
  Normal   Pulled                 75s   kubelet, docker-for-desktop  Container image "myapp:latest" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                74s   kubelet, docker-for-desktop  Created container
  Normal   Started                72s   kubelet, docker-for-desktop  Started container
  Warning  Unhealthy              65s   kubelet, docker-for-desktop  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.1.0.103:80/healthz/ready: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Now, I note that the `container` has `Status: Ready`, but the last event in the events list lists the state as `Unhealthy` because of a failed readiness probe. (Looking in the application logs I can see that there has been many more incoming requests to the readiness probe since, and that they all succeeded.)

How should I interpret this information? Does Kubernetes consider my pod to be ready, or not ready?

Comment: what can you see when you just run kubectl get po <yourpodname>

Comment: @Tim: Ah; under `READY` it says `1/1`, which I guess means the pod is OK. Is that the correct interpretation?

Comment: increase/double the initial deplay seconds and try again

Answer (score 4):

A pod is ready when readiness probes of all its containers return a success. In your case the readiness probe failed in first attempt but next probe was a success and the container went in ready state. Here in below example of failed readiness probe

the readiness probe below probed 58 times for last 11m and failed.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From                                   Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----                                   -------
  Normal   Scheduled  11m                  default-scheduler                      Successfully assigned default/upnready to mylabserver.com
  Normal   Pulling    11m                  kubelet, mylabserver.com  pulling image "luksa/kubia:v3"
  Normal   Pulled     11m                  kubelet, mylabserver.com  Successfully pulled image "luksa/kubia:v3"
  Normal   Created    11m                  kubelet, mylabserver.com  Created container
  Normal   Started    11m                  kubelet, mylabserver.com  Started container
  Warning  Unhealthy  103s (x58 over 11m)  kubelet, mylabserver.com  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.44.0.123:80/: dial tcp 10.44.0.123:80: connect:
```

also the container status is not ready as can be seen below

```
kubectl get pods -l run=upnready
NAME       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
upnready   0/1     Running   0          17m
```

In your case the readiness probe passed the health check and your pod is in ready state.

You can make use of initialDelaySeconds,periodSeconds,timeoutSeconds effectively to get better results. Here is a article.

[article on readiness probe and liveness probe](https://medium.com/platformer-blog/enable-rolling-updates-in-kubernetes-with-zero-downtime-31d7ec388c81)

Comment: Ah, thanks for the thorough explanation. I take it this means no event is emitted when the probe transitions to the success state?

Comment: yes the container transitions to ready state when readiness probe passes the health check and not ready when readiness probe fails the health check

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but is it correct that _no event is emitted for such transitions_?

Comment: For more info you can do a " Kubectl get pod <your_running_pod_name> -o yaml" and check the  lastProbeTime and check the messages. there will be messages like "message: 'containers with unready status"  if they are not ready.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/59844723/1569204 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/34599554/1569204. successful probes are not reported by kubectl describe (at least not by default).