# liveness probe for EKS daemonset

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, livenessprobe

I am trying to set up liveness Probe for my fluent-bit daemonset which basically runs a echo statement that should get pushed to stdout and available as container logs. I should then be able to use this log for alerting if the application is down.

This is my configuration

```
      name: aws-for-fluent-bit
      image: 'IMAGE_VALUE'
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      ports:
        - containerPort: 2020
      livenessProbe:
        periodSeconds: 60
        initialDelaySeconds: 600
        exec:
          command:
            - "/bin/sh"
            - "-c"
            - "echo '{\"health\": \"check\"}' || exit 1"
```

For some reason I do not see the health check message in the logs. What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Not reproducible with a nignx image, you should try doing `exec` into your container and run `/bin/sh -c "echo '{\"health\": \"check\"}'" || exit 1` to see if the command work.

Comment: It does work. I can see it echo the health check json.

Comment: @P Do you think this might be the reason? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34455040/kubernetes-liveness-probe-logging