# How can you specify an exec command with arguments in k8s deployment yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

I have a cli that does a few different operations on pod startup and can be run from inside the pod like `kubectl -n default -exec my-deployed-pod-xyz -- /path/my_cli -command health` and runs fine like that, it logs success messages and actually does what I want it to.

In that commmand it does `os.Exit(0)` if it succeeds and `os.Exit(1)` if an error occurs, as per usual (it's written in go but that's just a detail).

Unfortunately when I specify the command (the part to the right of `--` in the example above) as an exec in my kubernetes deployment yaml, it appears to always fail. To remedy this I made a `cmd_wrapper.sh` that just has:

```
#! /bin/bash

if /path/my_cli -command health ; then
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```

(maybe I don't need the if else but I thought I'd make sure).

Anyway when I use that as the exec command in k8s it works fine, which made me think the problem is the multiple words in the original command. I tried:

```
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /path/my_cli -command health
```

Also:

```
command:
 - /path/my_cli 
 - -command 
 - health
```

And:

```
command: ["/path/my_cli -command health"]
```

Also:

```
command: ["/path/my_cli", "-command", "health"]
```

Unfortunately none of these seemed to work. I can still use the bash wrapper script but would be nice to know what's going on here...

Edit: thanks to larsks I found the error log in the journal of the worker node, it looks like this:

```
Dec 18 14:32:33 mcrumzy-worker-1.nasa.gov kubelet[1068]:         rpc error: code = Unknown desc = command error: time="2023-12-18T14:32:33-08:00" level=error msg="exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: \"/app/my_cli -command health\": stat /app/my_cli -command health_check: no such file or directory"
```

So that doesn't help too much, just makes it look like it can't parse the command somehow. Escaping maybe?

Comment: "Unfortunately none of these seemed to work." Are they [producing any logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34455040/kubernetes-liveness-probe-logging)? Can you provide us with a reproducible example?

Comment: Well no because readiness probes and liveness probes don't produce any output.

Comment: Of course they do -- or they can, and they should in the event of a failure; that's why I linked to the answer that shows you how to get the output of failed readiness/liveness probes.

Comment: Hmm, you're right as it happens, at least on my setup, there is an error on the worker node journalctl - but in general it might not necessarily be anywhere I think, depending on various factors.

Basically file not found, which doesn't really get me anywhere.

I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This...

```
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /path/my_cli -command health
```

...is not a valid configuration. The argument to `command` (just like the argument to `command` in a container spec) must be a list of arguments. The error you're getting in your logs...

```
exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec:
\"/app/my_cli -command health\": stat /app/my_cli -command health_check: no
such file or directory"
```

...occurs because the system is looking for a file in `$PATH` named literally `/app/my_cli -command health`. There is no file with that name!

One of your attempts looks correct:

```
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
              - /path/my_cli
              - -command
              - health
```

(You can see that matches the syntax shown in [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-command).)

Update your Deployment manifest to use the above syntax, and then look and see if there's a new error message.